# Google maps platformで自作のルートをmap上に描画しても良い？

Tags: google-maps

標記の件、教えてください。
Direction APIでGoogleのナビゲーション機能（出発地と目的地をつなぐルートを算出する機能）があると思いますが、自分が引きたいルートを引いてくれないので、自作でルート探索アプリを作って、その結果をGoogle map上に描画するのって規約上問題ありますでしょうか？
下記の規約の条文の(c) No Re-Creating Google Products or Features.に抵触するかも。。。と感じました。
ご教示いただけますと幸甚です。

> 3.2.4 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services.
>
> (a)  No Scraping.  Customer will not extract, export, scrape, or cache Google Maps Content for use outside the Services. For example, Customer will not:(i) pre-fetch, index, store, reshare, or rehost Google Maps Content outside the services; (ii) bulk download geocodes; (iii) copy business names, addresses, or user reviews; or (iv) use Google Maps Content with text-to-speech services. Caching is permitted for certain Services as described in the Maps Service Specific Terms.
>
> (b) No Creating Content From Google Maps Content. Customer will not create content based on Google Maps Content, including tracing, digitizing, or creating other datasets based on Google Maps Content.
>
> (c) No Re-Creating Google Products or Features. Customer will not use the Services to create a product or service with features that are substantially similar to or that re-create the features of another Google product or service. Customer’s product or service must contain substantial, independent value and features beyond the Google products or services.  For example, Customer will not: (i) re-distribute the Google Maps Core Services or pass them off as if they were Customer’s services; (ii) create a substitute of the Google Maps Core Services, Google Maps, or Google Maps mobile apps, or their features; (iii) use the Google Maps Core Services in a listings or directory service or to create or augment an advertising product; (iv) combine data from the Directions API, Geolocation API, and Maps SDK for Android to create real-time navigation functionality substantially similar to the functionality provided by the Google Maps for Android mobile app.
>
> (d) No Use With Non-Google Maps. Customer will not use the Google Maps Core Services in a Customer Application that contains a non-Google map. For example, Customer will not (i) display Places listings on a non-Google map, or (ii) display Street View imagery and non-Google maps in the same Customer Application.

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　Google の規約を転載頂いているようですが、著作権の問題があるかもしれないため、引用元のURL等もご記載ください。その際、引用部分を範囲選択してエディタ上部の「“」を押すと引用ブロック扱いにできますので、お試しください。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、そちらから追記頂ければと思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: またスタック・オーバーフローでは、利用規約上の微妙な判断に関するご質問に対し、正面からの正確な回答をするのはなかなか難しいです。「過去こういうことをしたら駄目だと言われた」など、経験ベースの部分回答でよければ集まるかもしれません。もし正確な回答が早急に求められているのでしたら、Google の公式サポートにお問い合わせ頂く方が良いかもしれません。過去の議論として、[「法律についての質問をどう扱うか」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2726/19110)をリンクしておきます。

Answer (score -1):

既にGoogleがサービスとして提供している機能の「置き換え(コピー)」を作ってしまうと、APIを通したサービスの利用者から見て
機能の提供元(責任)がGoogleなのか開発者なのか分からなくなり、双方にとって好ましくない。APIを利用するなら
独自性のあるものを、と言っているように読めます。

Answer (score -1):

質問は、(c) No Re-Creating Google Products or Features.に抵触するかもということですが、そこに書いてあるのは`substantially similar`なサービスや製品を作るなということです。

`substantially similar`が、どういう意味かと言うと、[英語版 Wikipedia の Substantial similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantial_similarity)  には次のような説明があり、

> Substantial similarity, in US copyright law, is the standard used to determine whether a defendant has infringed the reproduction right of a copyright.

日本語でいえば、著作権関係で使われている「実質同一性」に近い用語だと思われます。

Googleの`Directions API`を使わずにルート探索機能を独自に実装して、探索の結果もGoogleのナビゲーション機能よりも良いものであれば、「実質同一性」があるとはいわないと思います。

恐らくGoogleの規約には抵触していないと思われるので、最終的にはGoogleに確認すればいいと思います。